# The solution of a system in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know whether it is correct if I say that, there might be a set of solutions of a system if there is a pivot in every row of the coefficient matrix, but not unique. And also, there will be a unique solution of a system if there is a pivot in every column of the coefficient matrix.

Another question is, will there be a pivot in every row of the coefficient matrix if there is a pivot in every column?

The matrix for both of the two situations is in echelon form.

Comment: Do we know anything about the dimension of the matrices ? In particular, do we have square matrices ?

Comment: It might be beneficial to future readers googling this question to retitle it. "Conclusion about consistent system" could mean anything.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you call a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your statement is essentially correct. The system $Ax = b$ will have a solution for every vector $b$ if and only if the row echelon form of $A$ has a pivot in every row. The system $Ax = b$ will have at most one solution for every vector $b$ if and only if the row echelon form of $A$ has a pivot in every column.